# Are there advanced Mapillary sequence editing tools (interpolation, streightening, key photos, etc)

Tags: mapillary

Is there a nicer way to edit Mapillary photo sequences? The online editor is very basic and only allows moving photos one by one.

Answer (score 0):

That's the only for now, after uploading. Before uploading, you can interpolate using the Mapillary command line tools: https://help.mapillary.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001753465-Uploading-with-Command-Line-Tools

If you're using the Desktop Uploader at the moment, it's likely that it will in the near future allow you to reposition sequences before uploading. You could use an app like Geosetter for now to move sequences in bulk prior to upload.